# Identifier not found (copy_impl)

Tags: c++, vector, stl

From mistake i deleted the vector file from visual studio. I got a pastebin, made again that file and put it in. Now when i want to compile a program which has vector.h, it gives me the error:

C3861: _Copy_impl, identifier not found

How to solve it?

I repaired visual studio, but still i get the same problem. I don't want to uninstall and install it again.

Comment: C++ header files are heavily tied in to their compiler. Unless you managed to reinstall the header file from your specific C++ compiler, and your specific version of your C++ compiler, it won't work.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I got a pastebin, made again that file and put it in

What pastebin? You can't just randomly reinvent one file from a standard library implementation. You need to put the original file back.

Reinstall Visual Studio, and take more care in the future. Ideally, a normal user wouldn't have permissions to alter system files like that.